com.​fasterxml.​jackson.​databind.​JsonNode-- gives security vulnerability issue URL An attacker can modify the URL scheme to access a local file
Title: Addressing URL Manipulation Vulnerabilities in Request Handling                                            Api call --> ResponseEntity fetch(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody JsonNode info) how to resolve security dependecny of the safe traversal of this issue, the custom input is used to later create files or maniupluation at multiple positions and extracting the data to set the things in my project Upon inspecting the code, we've identified a potential security issue related to URL manipulation vulnerabilities. The method passes the fetch directly to a sink method, fetch2, which performs sensitive computations. If the fetch contains user-controlled data that is used in URL construction, it could be manipulated by attackers to perform malicious actions such as accessing unintended resources or executing arbitrary code.
In our application, we have an endpoint /fetch/ that accepts JSON payloads containing information about events. This endpoint is implemented in the fetchmethod, which receives a HttpServletRequest and a JsonNode named info.
Upon inspecting the code, we've identified a potential security issue related to URL manipulation An attacker may access unintended files or make the application access a malicious website.
(jakarta.​servlet.​http.​HttpServletRequest, com.​fasterxml.​jackson.​databind.​JsonNode): A user-controllable string is used to specify a URL that is used in a connection. An attacker can modify the URL scheme to access a local file. An attacker can also mount a phishing attack by modifying,, how to resolve multiple such issues ?
I tried reaching the end method call after multiple calls and tried placing a regex to keep a check in the information being used, but didn't helped it

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
